# Using a count variable in a file name

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have a quick question. I just wanted to know if it was valid format (using bash shell scripting) to have a counter for a loop in a file name. I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
for((i=1; i <=12; i++))
do
  STUFF
  make a file(i).txt
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to make a bunch of files and don't need the loop for anything else, you can skip the loop altogether:

```
touch file{1..12}.txt
```

will make them all in one command.

If you have Bash 4, you can get leading zeros like this:

```
touch file{01..12}.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a quick demonstration. The `touch` command updates the last-modified time on the file, or creates it if it doesn't exist.

```
for ((i=1; i<=12; i++)); do
   filename="file$i.txt"
   touch "$filename"
done
```

You may want to add leading zeroes to the cases where `$i` is only one digit:

```
for ((i=1; i<=12; i++)); do
   filename="$(printf "file%02d.txt" "$i")"
   touch "$filename"
done
```

This will result in `file01.txt`, `file02.txt`, and so on, instead of `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`.

Comment: Good explanation. I would also add how ">" can be used to create files and truncate them if they already exist.